# I got this errors when creating this function (PlSQL)

Tags: oracle, plsql

team I received those error messages when I tried to create that fucntion
[image]

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Answer (score 0):

Comments show what you did wrong (plus one superfluous `begin-end` block):

```
create or replace function nombre_completo
  (p_id in hr.employees.employee_id%type)
return varchar2
is
  nombre_completo varchar2(100);    --> missing size
  nombre          varchar2(100);    --> missing size
  apellido        varchar2(100);    --> missing size
begin
  select first_name, last_name      --> wrong INTO clause
    into nombre, apellido
    from hr.employees
    where employee_id = p_id;

  nombre_completo := apellido;
  return nombre_completo;
end;
```

Though, as you select values you don't use and declare superfluous variables, that can be shortened to

```
create or replace function nombre_completo
  (p_id in hr.employees.employee_id%type)
return hr.employees.apellido%type
is
  nombre_completo hr.employees.apellido%type;
begin
  select last_name    
    into nombre_completo
    from hr.employees
    where employee_id = p_id;

  return nombre_completo;

exception
  when no_data_found then
    return null;
end;
```

I don't have your tables so I can't test it, but - generally speaking - that's how it should look like. Now, there might be other issues (e.g. perhaps you'd want to handle exceptions such as `no_data_found`), but that's another problem.

Comment: Thanks, that clarified my question. Fixed script but, now how do I add the exception you mentioned before

New script:

create or replace function Nombre_completo (p_id in hr.employees.employee_id%type) return varchar2
is
nombre varchar2(100);
apellido varchar2(100);
res varchar2(100);
BEGIN
select last_name into apellido
 from hr.employees
 where employee_id=p_id;
 select first_name into nombre
 from hr.employees
 where employee_id=p_id;
 res:='Su nombre completo es:'||' '||nombre||' '||apellido||' ';
 return  res;
end;

Comment: You're welcome. I added exception block into my last code; have a look. Oh, yes - don't post code as a comment, it is unreadable. Edit the original message you posted.